# 2015 Macbook Pro El Capitan - wifi drops when CPU active

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

When the CPU/GPU of my early 2015 13" Retina MBP running El Capitan 10.11.6 is under strain, the wifi drops.

I first noticed this whilst playing the web browser game diep.io in Chrome. When the game is running fairly CPU-intensively the wifi menu bar symbol turns to 'off' for a few seconds and then reconnects, hence booting me from the game. This happens intermittently - perhaps every 15 minutes. I thought it was related to the fan activating but I've observed it without fan too.

I've tested on 2 different wifi routers, both 2.4ghz, and with/without power cable - same results.

This is the only situation I've noticed the wifi dropping in - it doesn't drop randomly or suffer any other connectivity issues AFAIK.

Are there further tests I can run or solutions to try?

**Update**: some more tests

- Chrome with hardware acceleration off: no wifi drops, but game doesn't run hot enough to activate the fan
- Safari:  Game doesn't work
- Firefox with hardware acceleration: same as Chrome (no drops but no fan)

I'm thinking this may be simply a Chrome bug with hardware acceleration, but I'm worried the MBP hardware could be defective. Would testing with a non-browser-based CPU-intensive networked game or app be a good way to prove this?

Comment: As a test, do you observe the same behaviour when using a different browser to Google Chrome? As a second test, with Google Chrome, what happens if you go to Chrome > Preferences > Show advanced settings... and scroll to the very bottom and then disable _Use hardware acceleration when available_?

Comment: thanks @Monomeeth , I updated the question with your suggested tests

Comment: I am using android studio when ever any of my app loads something form Internet my wifi goes off even committing changes to remote repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the tests you've already run, and since your mainly concerned about your MBP's hardware, I'd also run Apple Diagnostics.

**Run Apple Diagnostics**

Follow the steps below to run Apple Diagnostics:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Regardless, take a note of what happens and let me know how you went.

Comment: Thanks again @monomeeth - it came back with no errors (ADP000) so it looks like a Chrome HA issue